# Dropbox Core API Search Within Files (grep)

Tags: android, grep, full-text-search, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm looking for a way to search for files that contain particular text like grep does but with the dropbox core api. The only search function I found only appears to search filenames and doesn't even support regex. Does anyone know a way I could implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just make a bash script that uses grep and outputs to a text file that my app will read.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, the Dropbox API doesn't support this. If you need to support this in an app you're building, you would need to maintain your own search index.